# CSS jumping animation

Tags: html, css

I'll try my best to keep it as simple as I can without being too vague. Basically, I'm making a simple web application, and I've attempted on multiple times to make my character.gif jump after a button being pressed, but I am struggling to apply the logistics to getting the objects current position, incrementing its % from top and right, and then decreasing it to give of a 'jumping' effect. Any pointers would be vastly appreciated. (I haven't included the code for the button, as all it does is change the .character class's animation to the jump). Thanks for any and all responses!

```
 .character {
      background-image: url('run.gif');
      background-size: 100px 70px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 70px;
      animation-name: characterMoving;
      animation-duration: 20s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      position: absolute;
      top: 80%;
      left: -1%;


    }

    @keyframes characterMoving {
      0% {
        left: -128px
      }
      100% {
        left: 100vw;
      }
    }

//do jumping animation here
@keyframes characterJumping{
  0% {

  }
  50% {

  }
  100% {

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not diving much into your code, but hope this will serve your purpose.

```css
.character {
      background-image: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faceavatars/PNG/D04.png');
      background-size: 100px 70px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 70px;
      animation-name: jump;
      animation-duration: 5s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      position: absolute;
      top: 20%;
      left: -1%;


    }


@keyframes jump {
  from, 20%, 53%, 80%, to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  }

  40%, 43% {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  }

  70% {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
  }

  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0);
  }
}

.jump {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
  animation-name: bounce;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="character"></div>
```

Comment: I've tried implementing your solution into my code, which has brought up a follow-up question. I slightly adjusted your code to make the animation make the player jump to the right (so they can jump over obstacles). From this, is it possible to update the objects position, instead of returning it to its default animation location (if this isn't clear enough, the animation will start on the left side of the screen at 5% of the screen width, and then after the animation completes, moving it to 10% of the screen width, it will return to the original 5% when i want it to stay updated at 10%)

Comment: And additionally, is it possible to get the sprites current position, and make it perform the animation from this location (as the sprite by default walks across the screen, and onTap, i want the jump action to initiate. Thanks for any feedback

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 .character {
    -webkit-animation: jump 1.5s ease 0s infinite normal ;
    animation: jump 1.5s ease 0s infinite normal ;
 }

@-webkit-keyframes jump {
  0%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  20%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  50%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  60%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
  80%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
 }
}
```